# Find a regular extension of domains on a string python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find extension "COM" from a sentence using regex in python.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'finding exstention from string on http://domain.coms/index/page/2'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'([^\s.\s\:]+\.[^\.\s\:]*)')
>>>
```

Result:

```
domain : 'domain.com'    ### notes: not domain.coms
url : 'http://domain.coms/index/page/2'
```

Comment: what is the expected result sir ?

Comment: the result of a string, sorry I forgot to give a little information about it.

Comment: @Tarjo you mean you need to extract `domain` from `url`??

Comment: yes, i want to find domain from str with python regex .

Comment: @Tarjo what's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you are looking for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'finding exstention from string on http://domain.coms/index/page/2'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'([^\/]*\.(?:com|en|org))')
>>> m = pattern.search(str)
>>> print m.group(1)
domain.com
```

Comment: How is this result different than what the OP originally got?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I dont know if the OP got the result or is still searching for that

Comment: thanks @aelor , but i want use many extentions like : '.com, .en,.org,'

Comment: then please whitelist the extensions you want like this : `([^\/]*\.(?:com|en|org))`

Comment: it works fine, but I am confused if I input extension into a variable, eg var = 'net|org|edu|com'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62966/discussion-between-aelor-and-tarjo).

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:([^\s.\s\:]+\.[^\/]*)(?:\/|$)[^\.\s\:]*))
```

Try this.`Group 1` will be the `url`.`Group 2` will be the `domain`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sK8oK9/1

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below.

```
>>> s = "finding exstention from string on http://domain.coms/index/page/2"
>>> m = re.search(r'(\S+?([^/.]+\.[^/]+)\S+)', s).group(1)
>>> m
'http://domain.coms/index/page/2'
>>> m = re.search(r'(\S+?([^/.]+\.[^/]+)\S+)', s).group(2)
>>> m
'domain.coms'
```